# How to keep timestamp when gsutil cp

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I am new to google cloud storage nearline and test it. I intend to use google cloud storage nearline for backup.

I wonder how to keep files timestamp when I do 'gsutil cp' between local and nearline.

```
gsutil cp localfile gs://mybucket
```

Then, uploaded file timestamp is set uploaded time. I want to keep original file timestamp.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry, you cannot specify the creation time of an object in GCS. The creation time is always the moment that the object is created in GCS.

You can, however, set extra user metadata on objects that you upload. If you'd like, you can record the original creation time of an object there:

```
$> gsutil cp -h "x-goog-meta-local-creation-time:Some Creation Time" localfile gs://mybucket
```

Answer (score 3):

When I attempted to perform copy with the following command, the timestamp (Linux "mtime") of local files gets automatically preserved as "goog-reserved-file-mtime" in metadata on Google Cloud Storage.

```
gsutil cp -r -P $LOCAL_DIR/* gs://$TARGET_BUCKET &
```

Comment: I think this is the preferred answer because the `goog-reserved-file-mtime` metadata is a standard that `gsutil` is using for preserving the modification time. So when you later copy the same object to a local file system, you will get the local file's modification time set to this value automatically (with `-P` option for `cp` and by default for `rsync`). With a custom metadata you will get object's creation date as a file's modification time, which is … not that cute.